# WPF animation paths speed and pause

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

Am new to animation in WPF and am attempting to re-code a program I have previously written using GDI+ and C++ into WPF and C#. The program uses animation paths to move specific images along these paths. I need to at some points on the path to either stop the attached image for say 5 seconds whilst all the other paths are still animating or change the speed of the attached image so the image slows down/speeds up at certain points. As im new to WPF I have a couple of choices but am not sure that there all possible :

1. Do each path in a separate storyboard, then using the pause/resume features of the SB and also using the speed ratio ? (Problems is I don't know if I can display multiple storyboards on the same canvas ?)
2. Use key frames somehow to set exact points where the animation will stop or change speed (don't know if you can do this with keyframes or there is another suitable animation class)

I would welcome comments on how is best to achieve this using either methods above or a completely different one as suggested by your good selves.

Regards
Stewart

Answer (score 0):

(not enough reputation here to comment, so I have to "answer")

1. Using multiple storyboards at the same time should be no problem as WPF also supports multiple animations targetting the same property values, multiple animations just running on the same canvas as a container should work fine.
2. To "pause" a keyframe animation, set two keyframes at the same position/value at different types. e.g. a property going from 0 to 5 to 5 to 10 with a few seconds in between. There's also "easing" in animation which can speed up/slow down according to different functions.

Can you provide a basic example of how the objects are supposed to move? As in: do they stop at the same point/time each time or are they depending on an outside influence like a mouse click?

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your input. I am glad to here using multiple storyboards is supported as this is the methods I had selected as the preferred one in my mind. I will also look into number 2 though in case I run up against any show stopping problems its always good to have a back up plan. The objects stop and change speed etc in different place, basically the user draws a path and then attaches an image to said path, the user can then play the animation and pause at a certain point and select an event to occur, this can be image change, speed stop, add text etc.